# How do I output this list of numbers via SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

I have a list of numbers in a SQL DB like so:

```
N1 | N2 | N3 | N4 | N5
----------------------
1  |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5
```

How do I figure out all possible combinations of this list and output them via query?

I took a look at [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Combinatorics/JohnsonTrotter.shtml) and I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Which RDBMS you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[numberstable](
    [n1] [int] NULL,
    [n2] [int] NULL,
    [n3] [int] NULL,
    [n4] [int] NULL,
    [n5] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
go
insert into numberstable values (1,2,3,4,5)
go
WITH range
AS (
SELECT N1 AS c FROM numberstable
      UNION  
      SELECT N2 FROM numberstable
      UNION  
      SELECT N3 FROM numberstable
      UNION  
      SELECT N4 FROM numberstable
      UNION  
      SELECT N5 FROM numberstable)
SELECT *
FROM range r1,range r2,range r3,range r4,range r5
    where r1.c <> r2.c and r1.c<>r3.c and r1.c<>r4.c and r1.c<>r5.c
    and r2.c <> r3.c and r2.c<>r4.c and r2.c<>r5.c
    and r3.c<>r4.c and r3.c<>r5.c
    and r4.c <> r5.c
order by r1.c, r2.c, r3.c, r4.c, r5.c
go
drop table numberstable
go
```

Answer (score 2):

Use cross-join:

```
DECLARE @id INT = 1;

WITH cte
AS (
      SELECT N1 AS c FROM #tab WHERE id = @id
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT N2 FROM #tab WHERE id = @id
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT N3 FROM #tab WHERE id = @id
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT N4 FROM #tab WHERE id = @id
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT N5 FROM #tab WHERE id = @id
)
SELECT *, CONCAT(c1.c, c2.c, c3.c, c4.c, c5.c) AS combined
FROM cte c1,cte c2,cte c3,cte c4,cte c5
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411994)**</kbd>

I've assumed that your table number has some sort of primary key.

**EDIT:**

Not prettiest solution to get permutations for distinct values but should work:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
      SELECT N1 AS c FROM #tab WHERE id = @id
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT N2 FROM #tab WHERE id = @id
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT N3 FROM #tab WHERE id = @id
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT N4 FROM #tab WHERE id = @id
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT N5 FROM #tab WHERE id = @id
),cte2 AS 
(      
  SELECT CONCAT(c1.c, c2.c, c3.c, c4.c, c5.c) AS combined
  FROM cte c1,cte c2,cte c3,cte c4,cte c5
)
SELECT cte2.combined
FROM cte2
JOIN #tab t
  ON CHARINDEX(CAST(t.N1 AS CHAR(1)), cte2.combined) > 0
 AND CHARINDEX(CAST(t.N2 AS CHAR(1)), cte2.combined) > 0
 AND CHARINDEX(CAST(t.N3 AS CHAR(1)), cte2.combined) > 0
 AND CHARINDEX(CAST(t.N4 AS CHAR(1)), cte2.combined) > 0
 AND CHARINDEX(CAST(t.N5 AS CHAR(1)), cte2.combined) > 0
 AND t.id = @id;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411997)**</kbd>

Probably the cleanest way to get permutations is to use recursive CTE.

Comment: This is good but I'm getting outputs with repeat numbers like : 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1. I need just the unique numbers in combos.

Comment: @plankton By combination you mean permutations? for 5 number should the result contain `5! = 120` rows?

Comment: After some research, yes I mean permutations.

Comment: Worked thanks! I marked the other guy's response as the answer just because it's cleaner, in case anyone else visits this post.

Comment: @plankton No problem, but you should add `WHERE ...` clause in case if table contains more than 1 row.